# A question about constructing $R$ from Dedekind cuts

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I am reading about the construction of the real numbers through Dedekind cuts and I worked through all of it but I don't understand one thing (on page 4). Why is the Archimedean property necessary for having inverses and opposites well-defined?

http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/~zeng/Teaching/math1006/dedekind.pdf

Comment: in the context of Dedekind cuts, $\sqrt{2}$ is the least upper bound of $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, x^2 < 2\}$, and this least upper bound property [implies  the Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Archimedean_property_of_the_real_numbers)

Comment: @user1952009 thanks. I am asking why it is necessary to have the Archimedean property for proving that inverses and opposites are well-defined. Can you please explain more because I don't see how your comment is relevant to the question

Comment: My comment means that you need to assume the [least upper bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) (and hence the Archimedean property) for the Dedekind cuts to be  well-defined

Comment: But @user1952009 it is possible to prove the least upper bound property just from the definition of Dedekind cuts (this is what is done in that paper, on page 2)

Comment: @user1952009 also the least upper bound property is a property of $R$ (real numbers), so how does the well-definition of Dedekind cuts depend on that, when Dedekind cuts themselves are used to define the real numbers?

Comment: When constructing the Dedekind cuts, you remark that $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}, x^2 < 2\}$ has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$, and you say "let's try to construct a bigger field where it has one (and **only one**)". For the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ with the Cauchy sequences of rationals it works exactly the same, so this least upper bound property is necessary and sufficient for constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$, and you probably have to look at the [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) for seing what it really means.

Comment: @user1952009 I am not following well. The least upper bound property, i.e. the completeness of $R$ as a complete ordered field containing $Q$, is one of the defining properties of $R$, but not the only thing that defines $R$. I don't understand why or how "this least upper bound property is a necessary and sufficient property for constructing $R$ from $Q$". I will check the hyperreal numbers.

Comment: the Dedekind cuts is exactly about constructing a field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ where every bounded set has [a least upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property)

Comment: @user1952009 I think I am understanding your point now. Thanks